# ES6 class controller not firing constructor

Tags: angularjs, es6-class

I just wanted to create a minimum working example for another problem, but already failed at that. I don't understand why the constructor of my controller class is not being executed. Does anyone have an idea?

```js
class Ctrl {
  constructor() {
    this.customers = [{
      id: 1,
      name: "Cust1",
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: "Cust2",
    }, {
      id: 3,
      name: "Cust3",
    }];
    alert("Constructor done!");
  }
}

angular.module('app', []).controller('Ctrl', Ctrl);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl as $ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="customer in $ctrl.customers">
      <input type="text" ng-model="customer.name">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Short answer: use a **newer version** of AngularJS. Change `1.2.23` to `1.7.2`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey well that was easy, thanks :D feel free to post it as an answer as it solved my problem :)

Comment: it's not an answer. An answer would be an explanation to why it doesn't accept Classes with older version of AngularJS. My guess, the way it was initiated, it didn't support new features of ES6, but I don't know what changed that allowed it.

Answer (score -1):

First you have to do updates/install some latest version of ES6 packages or modules.[please refer this link](https://www.timroes.de/2015/07/29/using-ecmascript-6-es6-with-angularjs-1-x/) for detailed information.

Sample Code#

```
export default class MyController {
  constructor() {
    this.name = "Bobby Tables";
  }
}

import {MyController} from './MyController.js';

angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MyController', MyController);
```